# Invalid Signature error when publishing iOS app

Tags: ios, publish, code-signing

I'm trying to upload a new version of my app to the App Store but I get this error:

> Invalid Signature. Code failed to satisfy specified code
> requirement(s). The file at path [MyApp.app/MyApp] is not properly
> signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution
> certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.
> Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the
> target level (which override any values at the project level).
> Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a
> Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain
> your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode,
> delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release
> target. For more information, please consult
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
> (ID: 3a7649b2-33eb-4c70-90a4-b3c87e5e699c)

Does anyone have some ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure you are not using Xcode Beta.

Comment: My Xcode version is 14.0.1 (14A400), not Beta

Answer (score 8):

I finally solved this issue.

I selected "Manually manage signing" and downloaded Apple Distribution certificate, then went back and selected "Automatically manage signing", and everything went fine.